# mysql join three tables not duplicate value

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join, no-duplicates

I have the following tables

```
--subscribers--

id
name
e-mail

--categories--

id
subscriber_id
cat1
cat2
... so on

--messages--

id
title
message
cat1
another field
...
```

My query needs to return title, message and subscriber mails. Every subscriber can get many messages.

My query returns duplicate e-mails. I would like to get:

```
e-mail1 - title1, message1
e-mail2 - title1, message1, title2, message2 so on
e-mail3 - title1, message1, title2, message2, title3, message3
```

Now I have:

```
e-mail1 - title1, message1
e-mail2 - title1, message1
e-mail2 - title2, message2
e-mail3 - title1, message1
e-mail3 - title2, message2
```

How to dela with it? Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can achive that by [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat). But without seeing your query...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use GROUP BY email to  get the unique email ids.

Use GROUP_CONCAT(title), GROUP_CONCAT(message) to fetch all messages